# What is a good approach to implementing a real time raster plot on Android?

Tags: android, c++, plot, opengl-es, kotlin

What is a suggested implementation approach for a real time scrolling raster plot on Android?

I'm not looking for a full source code dump or anything, just some implementation guidance or an outline on the "what" and "how".

*what*:  Should I use built in Android components for drawing or go straight to OpenGL ES2?  Or maybe something else I haven't heard of.  This is my first bout with graphics of any sort, but I'm not afraid to get a little dirty with OpenGL.

*how*:  Given a certain set of drawing components how would I approach implementation?  I feel like the plot is basically a texture that needs updating and translating.

***Background***

I need do design an Android application that as part of its functionality displays a real time scrolling raster plot (i.e. a spectrogram or waterfall plot). The data will first be coming out of libUSB and passing through native C++ where signal processing will happen.  Then, I assume, the plotting can happen either in C++ or Kotlin depending on what is easier and whether passing the data over the JNI is a big enough bottleneck or not.

My main concern is drawing the base raster itself in real time and not so much extra things such as zooming, axes, or other added functionality.  I'm trying to start simple.

***Constraints***

I'm limited to free software.

Platform: Android version 7.0+ on modern device

GPU hardware acceleration is preferred as the CPU will be doing a good amount of number crunching bringing streaming data to the plot.

Thanks in advance!